# How to return ID when new entry is recorded with a trigger express js and MYSQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am currently using express and workbench to configure a database where I can create, view and update cars.

Right now when I POST a new car it creates a new entry with the inputs manufacturer, model and price, and I use a trigger which I used inside workbench to configure a UUID for each vehicle. However, I want to be able to return this new UUID when a new record is created in my app.post function.

Here is my post function:

```
//Allow post methods 
app.post('/cars', (req, res) => {
    if (req.query.manufacturer && req.query.model && req.query.price) {
        console.log('Request received'); //logging to check if post request has beeen made 

        connection.connect(function(err) { //query the connection then call an SQL INSERT method to put new record in database. 
            connection.query(`INSERT INTO main.cars (manufacturer, model, price) VALUES ('${req.query.manufacturer}', '${req.query.model}', '${req.query.price}')`, function(err, result, fields) {
                if (err) res.send(err);
                if (result) res.send({manufacturer: req.query.manufacturer, model: req.query.model, price: req.query.price}); //sending the fields to the response (res)
                if (fields) console.log(fields);
                console.log(result)
            });
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Missing a parameter');
    }
});
```

Right now it just returns the new fields inputted in postman but not the new uuid (id) and am quite unsure how to do this, as it is created in a trigger in workbench:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` TRIGGER `cars_BEFORE_INSERT` 
    BEFORE INSERT ON `cars` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SET new.id = uuid();
    END
```

Comment: Do you also have an auto-increment column in the table?

Comment: I do not believe so as there is no need for auto-increment, as the UUID is generated randomly as the primary key.

Comment: It would make it easier to find the row that was just inserted, since you could use `result.insertId`.

Answer (score 1):

Query the table to get the `id` that was assigned to the manufacturer/model that was just inserted.

Also, use a database query with parameters rather than substituting request parameters directly into the SQL, to protect against SQL injection.

```js
connection.connect(function(err) { //query the connection then call an SQL INSERT method to put new record in database. 
  connection.query('INSERT INTO main.cars (manufacturer, model, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [req.query.manufacturer, req.query.model, req.query.price], function(err, result, fields) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      connection.query('SELECT id FROM main.cars WHERE manufacturer = ? AND model = ?', [req.query.manufacturer, req.query.model], function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err);
        } else {
          res.send({
            manufacturer: req.query.manufacturer,
            model: req.query.model,
            price: req.query.price,
            id: result[0].id
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```